# Do a synchronous http client fetch within an actix thread

Tags: rust, actix-web, reqwest

I have an actix endpoint, and I need to do a synchronous http client fetch to get some results, and return some data. My endpoints cannot use `async`, so I can't use any `.await` methods.

I've tried using reqwests blocking client in my endpoint like so:

```
{ ...

  let res = reqwest::blocking::get(&fetch_url)?
    .json::<MyResp>()?;
  ...
```

But it gives me the error:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'Cannot start a runtime from within a runtime. This happens because a function (like `block_on`) attempted to block the current thread while the thread is being used to drive asynchronous tasks.', /.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/tokio-0.2.9/src/runtime/enter.rs:19:5
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace.
```

Comment: Why can't your endpoints use async?

Comment: Long story but its an extremely complicated websocket server using traits, WSSessionHandlers, and Streamhandlers, with only async allowed at the top.

Answer (score 3):

you should try creating a new thread for that:

```
std::thread::spawn(move || {

    reqwest::blocking::get(&url).unwrap().json().unwrap()

}).join().unwrap()
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure out how to get it working with `reqwest` (it must have some weird conflicts with actix), but for some reason it worked fine with `chttp`.

`chttp::get(&fetch_url)?.text()?;`

Comment: It worked with an older version of Reqwest, but a more recent version made the blocking client the same as the non-blocking but wrapped with a `tokio::block_on`. Actix also uses tokio, which does not support nested runtimes.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot use **blocking** functions inside `async` functions.

Instead of `reqwest::blocking::get()` use `reqwest::get().await`.