# Messaging between two tokio runtimes inside separate threads

Tags: multithreading, rust, rust-tokio

I ran into the kind of a problem described in this question: [How can I create a Tokio runtime inside another Tokio runtime without getting the error "Cannot start a runtime from within a runtime"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62536566/how-can-i-create-a-tokio-runtime-inside-another-tokio-runtime-without-getting-th) .

Some good rust crates doesn't have asynchronous executor. I decided to put all such libraries calls in one thread which is tolerant of such operations. Another thread should be able to send non-blicking messages using `tokio::channel`.

I have programmed a demo stand to test implementation options. Call `tokio::spawn` inside of each runtime is made in order to understand a little more detail in tokio runtimes and handlers - it is a part of a question.

**The question.**
Please correct me if I misunderstand something further.
There are two tokio runtimes. Each is launched in  its own thread. Call `tokio::spawn` inside `first_runtime()` spawns task on first runtime. Call `tokio::spawn` inside `second_runtime()` spawns task on second runtime. There is a `tokio::channel` between these two tasks. Call `tx.send(...).await` does not block sending thread if channel buffer is not full, even if receiving thread is blocked by `thread::sleep()` call.
Am I getting everything right? The output of this code tells me that I'm right, but I need confirmation of my reasoning.

```rs
use std::thread;
use std::time::Duration;
use tokio::sync::mpsc::{Sender, Receiver, channel}; // 1.12.0


#[tokio::main(worker_threads = 1)]
#[allow(unused_must_use)]
async fn first_runtime(tx: Sender<String>) {
    thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(1));
    println!("first thread woke up");
    tokio::spawn(async move {
        for msg_id in 0..10 {
            if let Err(e) = tx.send(format!("message {}", msg_id)).await {
                eprintln!("[ERR]: {}", e);
            } else {
                println!("message {} send", msg_id);
            }
        }
    }).await;
    println!("first thread finished");
}


#[tokio::main(worker_threads = 1)]
#[allow(unused_must_use)]
async fn second_runtime(mut rx: Receiver<String>) {
    thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(3));
    println!("second thread woke up");
    tokio::spawn(async move {
        while let Some(msg) = rx.recv().await {
            println!("{} received", msg);
        }
    }).await;
    println!("second thread finished");
}


fn main() {
    let (tx, rx) = channel::<String>(5);
    thread::spawn(move || { first_runtime(tx); });
    second_runtime(rx);
}
```