# How do I call the Polars Rust API from an async function?

Tags: asynchronous, rust, rust-polars

I have an axum server that needs to scan some parquet files from S3. When everything is all sync, this works fine:

```rust
pub fn lazyframe_from_s3_key(key: &str) -> Result<LazyFrame> {
    let access_key_id = std::env::var("aws_access_key_id")?;
    let secret_access_key = std::env::var("aws_secret_access_key")?;
    let region = std::env::var("aws_region")?;
    let cloud_options = cloud::CloudOptions::default().with_aws([
        (Key::AccessKeyId, access_key_id),
        (Key::SecretAccessKey, secret_access_key),
        (Key::Region, region),
    ]);
    let mut args = ScanArgsParquet::default();
    args.cloud_options = Some(cloud_options);
    let df = LazyFrame::scan_parquet(key, args)?
        .with_streaming(true)
        .select([all()]);
    Ok(df)
}
```

However, as soon as I make it async and try to call it from a tokio managed async function, I get the "Cannot start a runtime from within a runtime" error, because scan_parquet calls block_on. Is there any way to get around this issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I create a Tokio runtime inside another Tokio runtime without getting the error "Cannot start a runtime from within a runtime"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62536566/how-can-i-create-a-tokio-runtime-inside-another-tokio-runtime-without-getting-th)

Answer (score 1):

I have come to the conclusion that there is no way to cleanly interact with polars in an async, and you have to resort to tokio::task::spawn_blocking any time you call a polars function that uses parallelism.