# Why futures::executor::block_on hangs in the poem handler

Tags: multithreading, rust, rust-tokio, rust-poem

```
use tokio::runtime::Handle; // 1.0.2
use poem::{
  get, handler, listener::TcpListener, middleware::Tracing, web::Path, EndpointExt, Route, Server,
};

fn inner_example(handle: Handle) -> String {
  let resp = futures::executor::block_on(async {
    handle
      .spawn(async {
        // Do work here
        reqwest::get("https://www.rust-lang.org")
          .await
          .unwrap()
          .text()
          .await
          .unwrap()
      })
      .await
      .expect("Task spawned in Tokio executor panicked")
  });

  resp
}

#[handler]
fn hello(Path(name): Path<String>) -> String {
  inner_example(Handle::current())
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), std::io::Error> {
  let app = Route::new().at("/hello/:name", get(hello)).with(Tracing);
  Server::new(TcpListener::bind("0.0.0.0:3000"))
    .name("hello-world")
    .run(app)
    .await
}
```

In this program, reqwest request is never called, and the program will hang.

I was following the instruction from https://stackoverflow.com/a/62536772/13208393, but it doesn't work on this case.

Answer (score 3):

> I was following the instruction from https://stackoverflow.com/a/62536772/13208393

You are *not* following the instructions from that post. The post uses `spawn_blocking` to execute the `block_on` from a non-async worker thread (`std::thread::spawn` is an other option).

You're not doing that, you're running `block_on` directly off of a runtime worker, so you're deadlocking the runtime.

Also... why are you using a sync handler if you want to call `reqwest` from within it? Just use an `async` handler and make `inner_example` async. You're creating problem you don't know how to solve for no reason.